# How to fix no variables echoed in PHP Post Request?

Tags: php, html

I am setting up a website and want to be able to obtain the customer number input for how many pizzas they want to order in Detailedsauceandquantitypage.html and post the number onto the ShoppingCartpage.php

I have already tried making my file a php file. I have already tried using POST.
The problem I am facing right now is not being able to output the number of pizzas ordered to the ShoppingCart.php page.

Detailedsauceandquantitypage.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <script src="script.js"></script>
            <title>Detailed sauce and quantity page</title>
        </head>

        <body>
            <h1>Detailed sauce and quantity page</h1>

            <form action="ShoppingCartpage.php" method="POST">

                <img src="bbq.jpg" alt="BBQ">
                <label for="numberOfSauces">Number of Pizzas (0-100):</label>
                <input type="number" name="bbqPizza" min="0" max="100">
                <input type="submit" value="Add this sauce to pizza">

                <br>

                <img src="tomato.jpg" alt="Tomato">
                <label for="numberOfSauces">Number of Pizzas (0-100):</label>
                <input type="number" name="tomatoPizza" min="0" max="100">
                <input type="submit" value="Add this sauce to pizza">

                <br>

                <img src="salsa.jpg" alt="Salsa">
                <label for="numberOfSauces">Number of Pizzas (0-100):</label>
                <input type="number" name="salsaPizza" min="0" max="100">
                <input type="submit" value="Add this sauce to pizza">

                <br>
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

ShoppingCartpage.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Shopping Cart page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Shopping Cart page</h1>
        <?php
        // define variables and set to empty values
        $bbqPizza = $tomatoPizza = $salsaPizza = "";

        if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) {
            $bbq = $_POST["bbqPizza"];
            $tomato = $_POST["tomatoPizza"];
            $salsa = $_POST["salsaPizza"];
            echo $bbq . " " . $tomato . $salsa . "\n"; die("Please 
        work!");
        }
        ?>
        <a href="OnlinePizzaOrderingPage.html">Add more pizzas to cart</a>
        <a href="Checkoutpage.html">Go to checkout</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Only one submit button in the form needed(at the end of the form before `</form>`)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <script src="script.js"></script>
            <title>Detailed sauce and quantity page</title>
        </head>

        <body>
            <h1>Detailed sauce and quantity page</h1>

            <form action="ShoppingCartpage.php" method="POST">

                <img src="bbq.jpg" alt="BBQ">
                <label for="numberOfSauces">Number of Pizzas (0-100):</label>
                <input type="number" name="bbqPizza" min="0" max="100">

                <br>

                <img src="tomato.jpg" alt="Tomato">
                <label for="numberOfSauces">Number of Pizzas (0-100):</label>
                <input type="number" name="tomatoPizza" min="0" max="100">

                <br>

                <img src="salsa.jpg" alt="Salsa">
                <label for="numberOfSauces">Number of Pizzas (0-100):</label>
                <input type="number" name="salsaPizza" min="0" max="100">

                <br>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add this sauce to pizza">
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

2.Add `name` attribute to button.

3.You have to modify PHP code a bit

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Shopping Cart page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Shopping Cart page</h1>
        <?php
            $bbq    = ( !empty($_POST["bbqPizza"]) ) ? $_POST["bbqPizza"] : 0;
            $tomato = ( !empty($_POST["tomatoPizza"]) ) ? $_POST["tomatoPizza"] : 0;
            $salsa  = ( !empty($_POST["salsaPizza"]) ) ? $_POST["salsaPizza"] : 0;
            echo $bbq . " " . $tomato . $salsa . "\n"; die("Please work!");

        ?>
        <a href="OnlinePizzaOrderingPage.html">Add more pizzas to cart</a>
        <a href="Checkoutpage.html">Go to checkout</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Note:- Always try to check `POST` data instead of `submit` button

Answer (score 1):

You should add name of your input button like this.

```
<input type="submit" value="Add this sauce to pizza." name="submit">
```

POST is read the name of the input not the type so you need to add name.